# Create table mysql with TIMESTAMPDIFF

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am converting some tables from my system that used sql server now to mysql, and am having a question in mysql how can I create a table with TIMESTAMPDIFF

Sql Server Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[login_user](
    [idx] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [client_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Login] [datetime] NULL,
    [Logout] [datetime] NULL,
    [Time]  AS (datediff(second,[Login],[Logout])),
```

Mysql Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login_user` (
  `idx` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `login` DATETIME NULL,
  `Logout` DATETIME NULL,
  `Time` AS TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,`login`,`Logout`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`idx`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

The table in mysql is not being created, because of the TIMESTAMPDIFF, any tips on how to work this in the creation of the table?

**my mysql is version 5.7.20**

Image Error:

[image]

Comment: You are missing the data type specification for the generated column. Try `Time` INTEGER AS (TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,`login`,`Logout`)).

Comment: @DanGuzman My god, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following syntax works on `MySQL 5.7`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login_user` (
  `idx` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `login` DATETIME NULL,
  `Logout` DATETIME NULL,
  `Time` INT(11) AS (TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,`login`,`Logout`)),
   PRIMARY KEY (`idx`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```